# How to Reshuffle Numbers in an array when one of the element in an array is deleted using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a JSON array

```
task= [{taskcode:1, taskName:'abc'},
       {taskcode:2, taskName:'abc1'},
       {taskcode:3, taskName:'abc2'},
           .....
      ];
```

When I delete task with the name `abc` the task code for other tasks should get reindexed like

```
task = [{taskcode:1, taskName:'abc1'},
       {taskcode:2, taskName:'abc2'},
           .....
      ];
```

These tasks are created dynamically by pushing values to tasks from a popup.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Don't include task code field in array. Task code could be the implicit index of the item. In this way you don't have to change index.

Comment: I'd go with @mggSoft 's suggestion. Much easier to maintain and you can delete tasks more easily

Comment: Just change the logic of your code so that the taskcode is equal to that task's array index. That way when deleting you can simply provide an index, which will be spliced from the array

Answer (score 0):

Since you `taskCode` directly correlates with the object's position on the array, why do you even have to bother with keeping it updated?  Any time you would access a specific object, you would know its position in the array and you could just add one at that moment.

So really your property is just `index + 1`.  For example, if you are displaying that taskcode to the user inside an `ng-repeat`, this would just work.

```
<div ng-repeat="task in tasks">
    <p>Task Code: {{$index + 1}}</p>
    <p>Task Name: {{task.taskName}}</p>
</div>
```

Or if you need to enumerate these `taskCode`s before some other operation, you could make a single loop to do that.  This would help prevent you from repeatedly re-indexing your array after every single small operation.  Now you can re-index it only when it's absolutely necessary.

```
$scope.enumerateTaskCodes = function() {
    $scope.tasks.forEach(function (task, index) {
         task.taskCode = index + 1;
    };
};
```

Comment: I am not populating the tasks in front end. the tasks arrays are created dynamically. I have to send the values to the Back end

Comment: @SathviSiva in what way?  Why can't you just dynamically create the `taskCode` right before making the server call?  You should consider adding more context to your question.